# NetBeans debugger stops on index.php with no breakpoint

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, netbeans-8

Whenever I start a debugging session in NetBeans IDE 8.1, the program always stops at this line in index.php:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
```

So I have to continue from there, even more than once sometimes, and its so annoying.

I tried to clear all break points but it won't work (this line is not even listed as a break point).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a break point exists? or you break it at beginning of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a config setting to control this

```
Tools->Options 
Click the PHP icon in the icon bar
Select the debugging tab
Uncheck the "Stop at first line" checkbox.
```

Comment: Awesome, thats what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: was looking for this for 2 days, who the hell though that checking it as default will be good idea